# Javascript help for a Chrome extension

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

**First of all, I am not a programmer. I do not know Javascript at all.** I'm trying to create a Chrome extension that modifies my browser tab's title, by taking a specific string on a webpage. I know how to create Chrome extensions (just barely) and I just need to modify the Javascript to do what I want (which I do not know how).

I found the following script online and am trying to modify it but can't figure out how to get it working. Here is the script:

https://pastebin.com/dY1LSdjT

```
// Fire this event any time the mouse is moving.  Sucks for performance, but it's a better experience
```

document.addEventListener("mousemove", function() {

```
// This will get us the banner
let bannerTextElements = document.getElementsByClassName("dijitReset dijitInputField dijitInputContainer");

 console.log(bannerTextElements);
 console.log(bannerTextElements[0]);

if (bannerTextElements[0]) {

     console.log("ok!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!");
     console.log(bannerTextElements[0].innerHTML);

    // This will get us the text
    let bannerTextLine = bannerTextElements[0].getElementsByClassName("dijitReset dijitInputInner");

     console.log(bannerTextLine);

document.title = bannerTextLine[0].innerHTML


}
```

}, false);

And here's the website viewed in developer mode. I would like to get the text "blahhhh" and use that for the title of my browser tab.

[image]

[image]

Below is a different webpage and the difference here is that the "div class" names will change. The numbers in those class will change to different numbers, but the structure and the overall name remains the same. For example, "ms-Button-label label-**549**" may change to "ms-Button-label label-**640**". This happens whenever you refresh the page. I found that the "viewport" id name doesn't change though, so I think if we can use that as a reference and then just look at the nested div classes and reference them and extract the value (in this case Crystal Mountain).

[image]

Answer (score 1):

### Fixing your code

You got like 95% of everything you need.
The one thing you are missing right now is that the fact that an `input` element does not posses an "innerHTML" (That is why it isn't closed like this: `<input>renderedText</input>`). Instead **you want to check for it's value:**

```
document.title = bannerTextLine[0].value;
```

#### Some Improvements:

**Search by ID**
You have a well defined input which can be more easily obtained by looking it up using the id:

```
let bannerTextLine = document.getElementById('lanDeviceIndex_searchBox');
```

### End result:

```
const bannerTextLine = document.getElementById('lanDeviceIndex_searchBox');

bannerTextLine.addEventListener("blur", function() {
    if (bannerTextLine != null) {
        document.title = bannerTextLine.value;
    }
});
```

This is the entire JS code. Note that I changed the event to **blur** which activates when the form is left, this should be optimal for your case.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your reply. As I've said, I know nothing about Javascript. The entire code that I pasted is written by someone else, not me. I can barely follow your answer. I have edited my original post, hope it makes it clearer.

Comment: Sorry, I tried to be descriptive on my answer. But what I have written in the "end result" part should just be what you are looking for. Try pasting it into your EventListener.

I just now see that you actually have an **id** on your input. Let me go over my code and adjust it so it is a bit easier again.

Comment: Perfect! It worked! I was trying to add the .value part into the code, but wasn't sure how to code it. I have a rough understanding of how this all works and your answer is a good reference for me, as I now can better understand how it all works. Thanks and very much appreciated!

Comment: Cool :)
Final edit with a better event listener, this should have you covered.

Comment: Hi Phy, sorry to trouble you again, could you please help me with another one? I've uploaded a new screenshot of the value I'm trying to pull. Please refer to my OP for the new screenshot. All the div classes and IDs changes, they don't have static names. The only static name is "viewport" and I've managed to pull that. But not sure how to reference the nested div classes to get the value...

Comment: I thing you would to a good job in describing the way how they change (best with code snippets) and also updating your Question in a way other people can understand it too.
Now a new person needs to understand what you are asking - see this comment and adjust accordingly.

Right now I also have no idea what should be done - if everything is dynamically than how do you determine which field to read from?

Comment: OK, so in that screenshot, the main id="viewport" does't change. However, classes such as "ms-Button-label label-549" will change to e.g. "ms-Button-label label-640". Any classes that has a number in the name will change to a different number whenever the page is refreshed. The value that I want to extract "Crystal Mountain" can be found in the "ms-Button-label label" class, just that everytime the page is refreshed, that class name changes. Considering that the id "viewport" name is static, can we reference that and then tell it to look at the nested classes and extract the value?

Comment: I really recommend you updating your main post so everyone has an easier time to understand what the current open question is and which information is available.


For your updated behaviour I think it depends. If you cant rely on classes or ids (besides the viewport one) the only other option of identifying the class you want to retrieve information from is structure.
In the last screenshot this structure looks like this:
main#viewport > div > div > button > div > div > div
This is not an ideal method and requires that the structure is always the same. Is this the case?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/209754/discussion-between-shadowz1337-and-phy).